# How to fix 500 error for PayUMoney payment gateway callback URL in OpenCart?

Tags: opencart, payment-gateway, payumoney

I have an OpenCart website. I have installed the PayUMoney plugin in it. 
The version of the Opencart is 3.0.2.

The issue I am having is when I try to place an order using PayuMoney payment gateway, After successful payment, I am getting an error of 500. This is when the callback URL called after successful payment.

Can some help me with this?

Comment: error 500 are internal server error. So you should check what exactly error in your server error log, or ask about that, your server provider.

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual error paste this right after the < ? php line in the index.php file.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

then refresh the page and the error should pop up instead, when you are done, you can take that code out.

IMPORTANT NOTE: Do this in maintenance mode so no real charges get passed. A page refresh has the probability to keep sending payment through.

Then you can come back here, or contact your server's tech support for more information.